# Understanding the timing of storing and retrieving an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, timing

I'm having a tough time understanding the timing of storing and retrieving private members in a Class. I'm simply trying to gather RSS titles from the XML file and display them in a TextView.

I Log'd the flow and it confuses me why the getTitleList() method is being called before the fetchXML() method is finished.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.digitalalias.dndandroid.rss;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String finalUri = "http://dndandroid.com/feed/";
    private HandleXML obj;
    private TextView tv, link, description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void fetch(View view) {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tv.setText("");  // prep textview for use

        obj = new HandleXML(finalUri);
        obj.fetchXML();

        tv.setText(obj.getTitleList());  // display rss titles
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + " Marc is cool " + finalUri);
        fetch(view);
    }
}
```

**HandleXML.java**

```
package com.digitalalias.dndandroid.rss;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.os.*;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by mfferguson on 5/2/2014.
 */
public class HandleXML {

    private String title = "title";
    private String link = "link";
    private String description = "description";
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean isEndTag = false;
    String linesep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

    public HandleXML(String url) {
        this.urlString = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getLink(){
        return link;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    public boolean getEndTagState() { return isEndTag; }
    public String getTitleList() {
        Log.i("Rss","The array in the getTitleList method. "+this.titleList.size());
        String ret = null;

        for (String temp : this.titleList) {
            ret = ret + temp + this.linesep;
        }

        return ret;
    }



    /**
     * fextXML
     */
    public void fetchXML() {
        Log.i("Rss","beginning of fetchXML");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i("Rss","in the try");
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);

                    Log.i("Rss","before parseXMLAndStoreIt from fetchXML.");
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    Log.i("Rss","after parseXMLAndStoreIt from fetchXML.");
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        Log.i("Rss","end of fetchXML.");
    }

    /**
     * parseXMLAndStoreIt
     * @param myParser
     */
    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        Log.i("Rss","beginning of parseXMLAndStoreIt.");
        int event;
        String text=null;
        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();

            System.out.println("before the while loop");

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name=myParser.getName();
                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(name.equals("title")){
                            this.titleList.add(text);
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("link")){
                            link = text;
                        }
                        else if(name.equals("description")){
                            description = text;
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                        break;
                }

                event = myParser.next();
            }

            System.out.println("after the while loop");
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Rss","The array after at the end of the method. "+this.titleList.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HandleXML class, the fetchXML method is creation a new Thread and calling the start() method on it. So it spawns a new thread getting the XML. Main thread is not 'waiting for the newly created Thread to finish execution. So the main thread continues execution and calls the getTitleList() method.

If you want to the fetchXML method to be asynchronous and to spawn new thread, you should have some blocking logic in getTitleList() method to see if the thread is still running and wait till it completes execution.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. I ended up learning how to properly use AsyncTask.